# Host node.js website and static website on different domains with nginx

Tags: nginx, web-server, domain-name

I'm struggling with the configuration of nginx on ubuntu.

I have a node.js website on domain1.com and a static website on domain2.com (HTML,CSS, client side javascript).

The node.js one does show up when using the domain1 but the domain2.com doesn't.

Here are the two config files I have in sites-available:

Domain1 :

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    server_name domain1.com domain1;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/domain1.access.log;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://IPOfServer:8080;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Domain2

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/domain2.com;
    index index.html index.htm;

    server_name domain2.com www.domain2.com;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/domain2.access.log;

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Are both files symlinked to sites-enabled?

Comment: Yes they are both.

Comment: Test configuration with `nginx -t`. Check that the DNS is set for `domain2.com`. Make sure you restart `nginx` to reload the new config.

Comment: Syntax is ok, test is successful. - I'm not sure how to check my DNS config.
Both are hosted on the same one, and I did exactly the same for both. - I have restarted nginx

Comment: From https://www.whatsmydns.net, it can't find domain2.com on any DNS.
I configured the domain 3 days ago. I don't understand.

Comment: Have you configured the domain2's IP address in your DNS registrar?

Comment: I forgot to configure the new domain in the host, where I have the dedicated server ! Thanks !!